# what is this error and how can I resolve it?

Tags: 12.04, error-handling

[image: Screen shot of error]

Whenever I start my PC, it shows up this message. It was not there until yesterday. It is giving me since today only. How can I solve it? Please help.

Comment: The problem is with the Unity-Music-lens. You can ignore it as @billybadass said. Or do it my way, remove the unity-music-lens from your system ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu sometimes gets some messages but you can still use your computer without telling any difference .

*Does your computer behaves differently* ?

make sure that your system is up to date .
Run from terminal

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

you can do your update for ubuntu's gui as well

if the problem persists the day after tomorrow there are still plenty of things you can do , start by specifying the error properly .

Comment: How can I update ubuntu's gui? secondly, should I wait for 2-3 days for observing that this message still persists or not? I have posted the pic of whole error message;you can see from there.

Comment: to update from gui go to dashboard and start typing update  , otherwise follow @suhaib solution , which is to remove unity-musi-lens or you can just let it be , it doesn't seem to cause any real damage , other than the error message .